# How to get row between an intervalle of row number?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible in sql server to get the lines from row 10 to row 20 for example ? 
I mean, I'm getting more than 1800 rows by querying the database and then i would like to display them 10 by 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
WITH ResultSetWithRowNumber AS 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MyField1) AS RowNumber, MyField1, MyField2
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE MyField2 = SomeValue
)
SELECT RowNumber, MyField1, MyField2
FROM ResultSetWithRowNumber 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE to add a column that represents row number of each row and then filter by that column.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT    *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) RowNum
    FROM      Table
)

SELECT *
FROM   MyCTE
WHERE  RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in SQL 2012+, use `OFFSET\FETCH`

```
....
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx